# add to array of a complext type in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

look at this code please :

```
var data = {                                
    "cell": [
    "1",
    "text1",
    "user1",
    "date1"
]};
```

this is an array contains just 1 element and now I need a code to set the following value into data variable:

```
data = {                                
    "cell": [
    "1",
    "text1",
    "user1",
    "date1"
    ]
},
{                                
    "cell": [
    "2",
    "text2",
    "user2",
    "date2"
]};
```

I use the following code , but it does not work.

```
var data = {                                
    "cell": [
    "1",
    "text1",
    "user1",
    "date1"
    ]
};

data += {                                
    "cell": [
    "2",
    "text2",
    "user2",
    "date2"
    ]
};
```

Note , I want to **ADD** to this array.i need a code to add another element to data variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an object. It isn't an array. If you want to add to it, you need to assign a value to a new property on it.

```
var data = {
    "cell": ["1", "text1", "user1", "date1"]
};
data.cell2 = ["2", "text2", "user2", "date2"];
```

Perhaps you want `data` to be an array of objects instead?

```
var data = [{
    "cell": ["1", "text1", "user1", "date1"]
}];

data.push({
    "cell": ["2", "text2", "user2", "date2"]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are not arrays, they're object literals. So what you want to do is merge two objects together.

See [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically):

> ```
> for (var attrname in obj2) { obj1[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
> ```
>
> If you're using a framework that craps all over your prototypes then
>   you have to get fancier with checks like `hasOwnProperty`, but that
>   code will work for 99% of cases.
>
> Example function:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Overwrites obj1's values with obj2's and adds obj2's if non existent in obj1
>  * @param obj1
>  * @param obj2
>  * @returns obj3 a new object based on obj1 and obj2
>  */
> function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
>   var obj3 = {};
>   for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
>   for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
>   return obj3;
> }
> ```

If you're using jQuery, you could use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect syntax. Should be:

```
var data = [{                                
    "cell": [
    "1",
    "text1",
    "user1",
    "date1"
]}]; 

data.push( {.....your new object....});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) This isn't an array, it's a object.

2) You can't have the same key twice in an object.

To add a key to a object use:

```
data['cell2'] = [
    "2",
    "text2",
    "user2",
    "date2"
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your data object from

```
var data = {                                
    "cell": [
    "1",
    "text1",
    "user1",
    "date1"
]};
```

you will see that it has a property cell that is an array with 4 elements. If that is correct if you want to add another cell you can make the data object an array like so:

```
var data = [{                                
    "cell": [
    "1",
    "text1",
    "user1",
    "date1"
]}]; 

data.push( {"cell": ["2","text2","user2","date2"]});
```

or you can add another cell property to the data object but it will need a different key or you will override the current cell property.

```
data['cell2'] = [
"2",
"text2",
"user2",
"date2"
];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set the data like this

```
data = [{                                
       "cell": [
       "1",
       "text1",
       "user1",
       "date1"
       ]
   },
   {                                
       "cell": [
       "2",
       "text2",
       "user2",
       "date2"
       ]
   }];
```

And to add a new cell to the data, do it like this

```
var dt = {                                
    "cell": [
    "3",
    "text3",
    "user3",
    "date3"
    ]
};
data.splice(data.length,0,dt);
```